# PDF File generated by POST Request Not Opening

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, pdf, post

I am sending a POST request to an API URL which is supposed to give the PDF file.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://ourDevEnv.com:5000/api/v1/Docs/Process",
    type: "POST", data: printData,
    crossDomain: true,  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success : function(data) {
            var WinId = window.open('', 'newwin', 'width=600,height=800');
            WinId.document.open();
            WinId.document.write(data);
            WinId.document.close();   
        }
});
```

On success I am opening the response data in a new window... But I am getting the following output...

```
%PDF-1.6
%����
5 0 obj
<</Length 2042/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x����o5�-���$�@Aڇ4M�Y����&-�h�����V��R�¿��c���y�kJ{�w�����3�c߽_~{����n��-���Ywp�\6�7׷ˣ����A����z�z�~�$�F4��Tچ1AE�0E�i>���Y����x�F��1Xa��k�n�m9�Ds�'؂7[o�\�}���|I�"w�x�,�G䀜�W��k��uj��;ʻƘ�2Q*���%Uv[�%o�9y�aKr�x#����s
ICm#:��[��B#�p��������'��-��1mm�|��
M����3�!���K0�)<�B������ߴ�C�  ���CP�����Sm{�VR�f[p:N[nɏ��wA����+Hh!oq��
V˙�Ԩm5n�/��y���?F!ح�B��g0�w�]���Sn   �5݃ǻ����Mh    �V�%�k��V~���>�/�{o|P.p��P�v�v:tK%ۖ�@�?�����@��kjLު��NS(�X7��z�Ru���a��(TĒL�7K��-�ʄt��M(���)y9�@�E��;VX���}�Eӡ!7�����)֥
�a�
more text like this...
```

The response header is

```
{
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "date": "Thu, 24 Mar 2016 09:18:28 GMT",
  "server": "Kestrel",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "application/pdf"
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong while making the POST request? or do we need to do anything else on the API side.

This is the code we use in ASP.NET to send PDF to the REST...

```
    Page.Response.Buffer = true;
    Page.Response.ClearContent();
    Page.Response.ClearHeaders(); 

    Document doc = reportGenerator.RenderDocument();
    Stream m = Response.OutputStream;

    PdfExportFilter pdf = new PdfExportFilter();
    pdf.KeepOriginalImageResolutionAndQuality = true;
    pdf.ImageQuality = 200;
    pdf.Export(doc, m); 

    Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Page.Response.End();
```

Some help would be great...

Comment: try to change your ajax like this  `$.ajax({
        url: '<url_to_pdf>',
        success: function(data) {
            var blob=new Blob([data]);
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download="Dossier_"+new Date()+".pdf";
            link.click();
        }
    });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use document.write to view a PDF.
2. The data you receive from $.ajax isn't binary so the pdf data is corrupt.

You can use XMLHttpRequest to get the pdf data as a blob and create a blob url to use to open the window.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var WinId = window.open(url.createObjectURL(this.response);, 'newwin', 'width=600,height=800');
    }
}
xhr.open('POST', 'http://ourDevEnv.com:5000/api/v1/Docs/Process');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send(printData);
```

Comment: Open a window with object URL don't works on IE. You should pass the blob to function "window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob"

Answer (score 0):

you can use below sample code to get pdf from a post request or webservice.

```
function getDocumentByXMLHttpRequest() {
    //reason for this
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199155/pdf-file-generated-by-post-request-not-opening
    var header = getHeader();
    var requesturl =  < url rest service url to fetch document >
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', requesturl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header.key, header.value);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            onloadDocumentFromContent(this.response);
        } else {
            navigator.notification.alert('Error while requesting pdf with id ' + getDocumentId());

        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
function onloadDocumentFromContent(pdfraw) {

    var docInitParams = {
        data : pdfraw
    };

    PDFJS.getDocument(docInitParams).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
        pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

        // Initial/first page rendering

        renderPage(pageNum);
    });

}
```